# operator< error in priority queue

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I am facing "binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Baloons' (or there is no acceptable conversion)" error and I cannot find any solution?

I would also like to ask how can I order the priority queue by baloon.end?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Baloons
{
public:
    float start;
    float end;

public:
    Baloons() {}
    Baloons(float start, float end) : start{ start }, end{ end } {}
};

int main()
{
Baloons baloon1(1, 5);
Baloons baloon2(4, 7);
Baloons baloon3(6, 9);
Baloons baloon4(11, 12);
std::priority_queue<Baloons> myBaloons;
myBaloons.push(baloon1);
myBaloons.push(baloon2);
myBaloons.push(baloon3);
myBaloons.push(baloon4);
while (!myBaloons.empty())
{
    Baloons b = myBaloons.top();
    cout << b.start << " -> " << b.end << " ";
    myBaloons.pop();
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I'm actually surprised I don't get a specific result here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22binary+%27%3C%27%3A+no+operator+found+which+takes+a+left-hand+operand+of+type%22 considering how much `<` is used in standard collections and algorithms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `operator<` to you ballons class, for example:

```
bool operator<(const Baloons& rhs) const {
  return std::make_pair(start,end) < std::make_pair(rhs.start,rhs.end);
}
```

it will be used to order elements in your collection

Comment: Thank you for helping me and I appreciate for not judging my problem as a homework.

Answer (score 0):

Priority queues are sorted containers, but the compiler doesn't know how to sort `Baloons`.  You have to define a custom `operator<` so your container can be sorted.

This is clearly a homework problem (pretty sure this was created just for the 'myBaloons.pop()' joke) so I don't want to give the whole thing away...  Add something like this to your Baloons class.

```
bool operator<(const Baloons& rhs) const {
    // return true if this Baloons is less than 'rhs'
}
```

That way your Baloons can be compared.  (e.g. `if (baloon1 < baloon2) { /* do stuff */ }`)  The priority queue does this comparison behind the scenes as you insert new objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an overloaded `operator<` for `Baloons` otherwise the compiler doesn't know how to order the elements of the `std::priority_queue<Baloons>`. For example, define something like this in your `Baloons` class:

```
bool operator<(const Baloons& _other) const {
    return end < _other.end;
}
```

Or whatever you want to compare in-place of the `return` statement here.

Answer (score 0):

Provide `bool operator < (const Baloons&, const Baloons&)`,

```
bool operator < (const Baloons& lhs, const Baloons& rhs)
{
    return lhs.end < rhs.end;
}
```

or create a functor `CustomComparer` and give it to `std::priority_queue<Ballons, std::vector<Ballons>, CustomComparer>`

```
struct CustomComparer
{
    bool operator () (const Baloons& lhs, const Baloons& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.end < rhs.end;
    }
};
```

and later

```
std::priority_queue<Ballons, std::vector<Ballons>, CustomComparer> myBaloons;
```